# Resize height of picture and extend width

Tags: photoshop

i have some picture which is 675x503. I would like to make more width on it and let's say to 1024 and in height to 400. How to do that without cutting my image and keep quality? I just would like to have this image on my website top. I got photoshop 6. I tried with Image->image size but its not what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to cut the picture at all, this will distort the image due to different height and width ratios. If this is not an issue, you could simply hit ctrl(or cmd)+t when the layer with the picture is selected. It will let you resize and rotate the entire image. There is also an option in the Image -> Image Size menu called "Bicubic Sharper", found in the drop-down list at the bottom of the menu(Photoshop CS6). It's meant for image reduction and should also solve your problem.